# multiple vedio rtsp stream inference using yolov8 cant show different vedio stream's result

Tags: python, yolov8

It seems some problems in showwing mutiple RTSP streams in realtime
I'm using following code to inference multiple streams, and to show the result image

```py
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from PIL import Image

model = YOLO('yolov8m-pose.pt')
source = './list.streams'

results = model(source, stream=True)

for result in results:
    annotated_image = result.plot()
    cv2.imshow(f'{result.path}', annotated_image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
the list.streams is like
```

```
rtsp://user:password@172.20.0.183:554/Streaming/Channels/101
rtsp://user:password@172.20.4.214:554/Streaming/Channels/101
rtsp://user:password@172.20.3.40:554/Streaming/Channels/101
```

run the upper code, the terminal print like:

> rtsp://user:password@172.20.0.183:554/Streaming/Channels/101 Success ✅
> (inf frames of shape 1920x1080 at 25.00 FPS)
> rtsp://user:password@172.20.4.214:554/Streaming/Channels/101 Success ✅
> (inf frames of shape 1920x1080 at 25.00 FPS)
> rtsp://user:password@172.20.3.40:554/Streaming/Channels/101 Success ✅
> (inf frames of shape 1920x1080 at 25.00 FPS)

But, when i think the cv2.imshow function will show the three different streams inference results, it JUST show the three windows render the same video stream.

is there some friends meet the same problem like me. how did you solve the problem?